# OConcurrentModificationException in OrientGraph

Tags: java, orientdb

I am getting the following exception when I try to save a OrientGraph database.

Here is my code where I have implemented the commit.

Code:

```
    OrientGraph orientGraph = null;
    String source = enrichData.getSource();


    orientGraph = orientConfiguration.open();
    LocationDocument location = enrichData.getGeoLocation();

    Vertex locationVertex = null;
    Vertex contentVertex = null;
    Vertex userVertex = null;

    if ((location != null) && !location.isNull()) {
        locationVertex = getLocationVertex(location, orientGraph);
    }

    ContentDocument content = enrichData.getContent();
    if ((content != null) && (StringUtils.isNotBlank(content.getTweetId()))) {
        contentVertex = getContentVertex(orientGraph, content, source);
    }

    UserDocument user = enrichData.getUserInfo();
    if ((user != null) && (StringUtils.isNotBlank(user.getUserId()))) {
        userVertex = createUser(orientGraph, user, source);
    }

    if (locationVertex != null) {
        orientGraph.addEdge(null, userVertex, locationVertex, "lives_at");
    }
    if ((contentVertex != null) && (userVertex != null)) {
        orientGraph.addEdge(null, contentVertex, userVertex, "posted_by");
    }
    orientGraph.commit();

    if (orientGraph != null) {
        orientConfiguration.close(orientGraph);
    }
```

Output:

```
      java.lang.RuntimeException: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OConcurrentModificationException: Cannot UPDATE the record #13:8 because the version is not the latest. Probably you are updating an old record or it has been modified by another user (db=v7 your=v6)
at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:90) ~[storm-core-0.9.0.1.jar:na]
at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchWhenAvailable(DisruptorQueue.java:61) ~[storm-core-0.9.0.1.jar:na]
at backtype.storm.disruptor$consume_batch_when_available.invoke(disruptor.clj:62) ~[storm-core-0.9.0.1.jar:na]
at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3498$fn__3510$fn__3557.invoke(executor.clj:730) ~[storm-core-0.9.0.1.jar:na]
at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__444.invoke(util.clj:403) ~[storm-core-0.9.0.1.jar:na]
at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0_17]
Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OConcurrentModificationException: Cannot UPDATE the record #13:8 because the version is not the latest. Probably you are updating an old record or it has been modified by another user (db=v7 your=v6)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage.updateRecord(OLocalPaginatedStorage.java:797) ~[orientdb-core-1.7.6.jar:1.7.6]
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.raw.ODatabaseRaw.save(ODatabaseRaw.java:273) ~[orientdb-core-1.7.6.jar:1.7.6]
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.ODatabaseRecordAbstract.executeSaveRecord(ODatabaseRecordAbstract.java:1132) ~[orientdb-core-1.7.6.jar:1.7.6]
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionOptimistic.addRecord(OTransactionOptimistic.java:422) ~[orientdb-core-1.7.6.jar:1.7.6]
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionOptimistic.saveRecord(OTransactionOptimistic.java:365) ~[orientdb-core-1.7.6.jar:1.7.6]
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.ODatabaseRecordTx.save(ODatabaseRecordTx.java:319) ~[orientdb-core-1.7.6.jar:1.7.6]
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.ODatabaseRecordTx.save(ODatabaseRecordTx.java:40) ~[orientdb-core-1.7.6.jar:1.7.6]
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.ORecordAbstract.save(ORecordAbstract.java:334) ~[orientdb-core-1.7.6.jar:1.7.6]
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument.save(ODocument.java:1458) ~[orientdb-core-1.7.6.jar:1.7.6]
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument.save(ODocument.java:1447) ~[orientdb-core-1.7.6.jar:1.7.6]
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument.save(ODocument.java:1436) ~[orientdb-core-1.7.6.jar:1.7.6]
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument.save(ODocument.java:81) ~[orientdb-core-1.7.6.jar:1.7.6]
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.ridbag.embedded.OEmbeddedRidBag.serialize(OEmbeddedRidBag.java:291) ~[orientdb-core-1.7.6.jar:1.7.6]
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.ridbag.ORidBag.toStream(ORidBag.java:222) ~[orientdb-core-1.7.6.jar:1.7.6]
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.string.ORecordSerializerCSVAbstract.fieldToStream(ORecordSerializerCSVAbstract.java:542) ~[orientdb-core-1.7.6.jar:1.7.6]
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.string.ORecordSerializerSchemaAware2CSV.toString(ORecordSerializerSchemaAware2CSV.java:495) ~[orientdb-core-1.7.6.jar:1.7.6]
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.string.ORecordSerializerStringAbstract.toStream(ORecordSerializerStringAbstract.java:669) ~[orientdb-core-1.7.6.jar:1.7.6]
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.string.ORecordSerializerSchemaAware2CSV.toStream(ORecordSerializerSchemaAware2CSV.java:258) ~[orientdb-core-1.7.6.jar:1.7.6]
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.ORecordSchemaAwareAbstract.toStream(ORecordSchemaAwareAbstract.java:420) ~[orientdb-core-1.7.6.jar:1.7.6]
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.ORecordSchemaAwareAbstract.toStream(ORecordSchemaAwareAbstract.java:415) ~[orientdb-core-1.7.6.jar:1.7.6]
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument.toStream(ODocument.java:446) ~[orientdb-core-1.7.6.jar:1.7.6]
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage.commitEntry(OLocalPaginatedStorage.java:2102) ~[orientdb-core-1.7.6.jar:1.7.6]
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage.commit(OLocalPaginatedStorage.java:1078) ~[orientdb-core-1.7.6.jar:1.7.6]
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionOptimistic.doCommit(OTransactionOptimistic.java:132) ~[orientdb-core-1.7.6.jar:1.7.6]
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionOptimistic.commit(OTransactionOptimistic.java:105) ~[orientdb-core-1.7.6.jar:1.7.6]
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.ODatabaseRecordTx.commit(ODatabaseRecordTx.java:142) ~[orientdb-core-1.7.6.jar:1.7.6]
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.commit(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:504) ~[orientdb-core-1.7.6.jar:1.7.6]
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.commit(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:496) ~[orientdb-core-1.7.6.jar:1.7.6]
at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.commit(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:1096) ~[orientdb-server-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.executeRequest(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:344) ~[orientdb-server-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.OBinaryNetworkProtocolAbstract.execute(OBinaryNetworkProtocolAbstract.java:169) ~[orientdb-server-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
at com.orientechnologies.common.thread.OSoftThread.run(OSoftThread.java:45) ~[orient-commons-1.7.6.jar:1.7.6]
```

Answer (score 1):

This exception happens because you're running in a Multi Version Control Check (MVCC) system and another thread/user has updated the record you're saving. To fix this problem you can:

if you're running in a multi-thread application and your JVM is the only client is writing to the database then disabling the Level1 cache could be enough.
If you're using the GraphDB API look at: concurrency
If you want to leave the MVCC and write code concurrency proof:

```
for (int retry = 0; retry < maxRetries; ++retry) {
  try {
    // APPLY CHANGES
    document.field(name, "Luca");

    document.save();
    break;
  } catch(ONeedRetryException e) {
    // RELOAD IT TO GET LAST VERSION
    document.reload();
  }
}
```

The same in transactions:

```
for (int retry = 0; retry < maxRetries; ++retry) {
  db.begin();
  try {
    // CREATE A NEW ITEM
    ODocument invoiceItem = new ODocument("InvoiceItem");
    invoiceItem.field(price, 213231);
    invoiceItem.save();

    // ADD IT TO THE INVOICE
    Collection<ODocument> items = invoice.field(items);
    items.add(invoiceItem);
    invoice.save();

    db.commit();
    break;
  } catch (OTransactionException e) {
    // RELOAD IT TO GET LAST VERSION
    invoice.reload();
  }
}
```

Where **maxRetries** is the maximum number of attempt of reloading.

For more information look at the official documentation: http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/last/orientdb.wiki/Troubleshooting-Java.html

Comment: Last version of record doesn't contain updated values ? Do you know why?